# How to move footline up a bit?

Tags: header-footer, margins

I want to move up my footline a bit, say 0,5cm , but still keep it within the bottom 2,5cm margin.

How to do so as easy as possible?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headings=small]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Set `footskip=<dimen>`

Answer (score 2):

`geometry` has a large number of options that allow to do this kind of stuff. For example, you can set the distance between textarea an footer explicitly via `footskip=some value`. The documentation is quite good, so have a look at geometry.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the `geometry` package can solve this:

Just add `footskip=1cm` to get a 1cm margin from the bottom. Your MWE should look like that then:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headings=small]{scrreprt}
% inserted footskip
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,a4paper,footskip=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most page geometry lengths are calculated when the class is loaded or when the geometry package or one of its commands such as `\newgeometry`, `\restoregeometry` are used. As the other answers stated setting the `footskip` length can easily be done using the `geometry` package. Such lengths if you are in a hurry, can also be set simply by:

```
 \setlength\footskip{1cm}
```

Example code,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headings=small]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\setlength\footskip{1cm}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```